# Defining numerical variables in latex preamble

Tags: overleaf, preamble, variable, vspace

In my manuscript, I need to specify the `vspace` command in a few places. I wonder if I can define numerical variables for this purpose in an `article` document class. For example, instead of typing `\vspace{1cm}`, I would like to define a variable, such as `x = 1cm` and use `x` inside my `vspace`. Ideally, I would like to have multiple variables `x1, x2, x3` that I can use each of them in their appropriate places, and by setting them in preamble I will not need to go through every single `vspace` manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a length variable with

```
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{1cm}
```

and then you'll be able to use it, e.g.

```
\vspace{\mylength}
```